# gdalbuildvrt does not support heterogeneous band scale

Tags: gdal, gdalbuildvrt

I need to merge about 300 geotiff files, and I choose to use the gdalbuildvrt. However I got one problematic file, which caused the error as following:
`Warning 6: gdalbuildvrt does not support heterogeneous band scale: expected (1,0.010000), got (0,1.000000).`

Does anyone know how to revise the band scale for the geotiff file? I tried the rasterio, but failed:

```
    with rio.open(output_image, 'w', scale=0.01) as dst:
        dst.write(img, 1)
```

**The gdalinfo of the wrong file is**

```
Files: ********
Size is 1200, 1200
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["unnamed",
    BASEGEOGCRS["Unknown datum based upon the custom spheroid",
        DATUM["Not_specified_based_on_custom_spheroid",
            ELLIPSOID["Custom spheroid",6371007.181,0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["Sinusoidal",
        METHOD["Sinusoidal"],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (6671703.117999999783933,6671703.117999999783933)
Pixel Size = (926.625433055833810,-926.625433055833014)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  HDFEOSVersion=HDFEOS_V2.17
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 6671703.118, 6671703.118) (120d 0' 0.00"E, 60d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  ( 6671703.118, 5559752.598) ( 93d20'36.35"E, 50d 0' 0.00"N)
Upper Right ( 7783653.638, 6671703.118) (140d 0' 0.00"E, 60d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 7783653.638, 5559752.598) (108d54' 2.40"E, 50d 0' 0.00"N)
Center      ( 7227678.378, 6115727.858) (113d19'26.55"E, 55d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=1200x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
```

**The gdalinfo of the right file is**

```
Files: ********
Size is 1200, 1200
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["unnamed",
    BASEGEOGCRS["Unknown datum based upon the custom spheroid",
        DATUM["Not_specified_based_on_custom_spheroid",
            ELLIPSOID["Custom spheroid",6371007.181,0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["Sinusoidal",
        METHOD["Sinusoidal"],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (6671703.117999999783933,5559752.598333000205457)
Pixel Size = (926.625433055833810,-926.625433055000258)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  ASSOCIATEDINSTRUMENTSHORTNAME.1=MODIS
  ASSOCIATEDPLATFORMSHORTNAME.1=Terra
  ASSOCIATEDSENSORSHORTNAME.1=MODIS
  BANDDEFINITION=END_OBJECT
  CHARACTERISTICBINSIZE=926.6
  DATACOLUMNS=1200
  DATAROWS=1200
  DATASETNAME=GLASS06A01
  DAYNIGHTFLAG=Both
  EASTHBOUNDINGCOORDINATE=109.112804
  EXCLUSIONGRINGFLAG=N
  GLOBALGRIDCOLUMNS=43200
  GLOBALGRIDROWS=21600
  GRIDTYPE=Sinusoidal
  GRINGPOINTLATITUDE.1=50.091797,49.984305,39.771465,39.849042
  GRINGPOINTLONGITUDE.1=93.392666,109.112804,91.359893,78.151152
  GRINGPOINTSEQUENCENO.1=1,2,3,4
  HDFEOSVersion=HDFEOS_V2.20
  HORIZONTALTILENUMBER=24
  INPUTFILESNAME=Multi-Source Data
  INPUTPOINTER=Multi-Source Data
  INSTITUTENAME=BEIJING
  LOCALGRANULEID=GLASS06A01.V01.A2010090.h24v04.2021212.hdf
  LOCALVERSIONID=V01
  long_name=Land surface temperature 1km SIN Grid
  NORTHBOUNDINGCOORDINATE=50.091797
  PARAMETERNAME.1=GLASS06A01
  PGEVERSION=V01
  PROCESSINGENVIRONMENT=High Performance Computing System
  PRODUCTDATEANDTIME=2021-07-31 16:25:41
  PRODUCTIONDATETIME=2021-07-31 16:25:41
  PRODUCTNAME=END_OBJECT
  PRODUCTQUALITY=CLOUDREMOVED
  REPROCESSINGACTUAL=reprocessed
  REPROCESSINGPLANNED=further update is anticipated
  scale_factor=0.01
  SHORTNAME=GLASS06A01
  SOUTHBOUNDINGCOORDINATE=39.771465
  TILENUMBER=H24V04
  units=K
  VERSIONID=1
  VERTICALTILENUMBER=04
  WEBSITE=http://glass-product.bnu.edu.cn
  WESTHBOUNDINGCOORDINATE=78.151152
  _FillValue=0
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 6671703.118, 5559752.598) ( 93d20'36.35"E, 50d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  ( 6671703.118, 4447802.079) ( 78d19'27.97"E, 40d 0' 0.00"N)
Upper Right ( 7783653.638, 5559752.598) (108d54' 2.40"E, 50d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 7783653.638, 4447802.079) ( 91d22'42.64"E, 40d 0' 0.00"N)
Center      ( 7227678.378, 5003777.339) ( 91d55'25.97"E, 45d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=1200x3 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = Land surface temperature 1km SIN Grid
  NoData Value=0
  Unit Type: K
  Offset: 0,   Scale:0.01
```

Comment: You say that one file is wrong but what do you mean by that? Do you mean that is actually has the same scale:0.01 than the other images but it has wrong metadata? Or is the image OK but it is just unscaled while the others are scaled?

Comment: Actually, it is inappropriate to say the file is wrong, these files are LST products produced by someone, I do not know why one specific file missed some processing, it was not multiplied by the scale factor, i.e. 100. 
I used rasterio to multiply the pixel value of the image by 100, but I could not change the scale information in gdalinfo to 0.01, and this led to gdalbuildvrt reporting error. @user30184

Comment: Is the missing piece to update the metadata of the GeoTIFF to include Scale:0.01?

Comment: I guess so. But I can't figure out how to update the metadata of the GeoTIFF to include Scale:0.01. @user30184

Comment: Use this https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I tried the command `gdal_edit.py -scale 0.01 A2010090.h24v03.2021212.tif`, and then merged the files using gdalbuildvrt, it worked perfectly! @user30184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gdal_edit.py Python script https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html can be used for editing the metadata of GeoTIFF and other raster files. The utility has a special switches for editing the scale and offset values. You need to use just `-scale`.

> **-scale** <value>
>
> Assign a specified scale value to output bands. If a single scale value is
> provided it will be set for all bands.
> Alternatively one scale value per band can be provided, in which case
> the number of scale values must match the number of bands. If no scale
> is needed, it it recommended to set the value to 1. Scale and Offset
> are generally used together. For example, scale and offset might be
> used to store elevations in a unsigned 16bit integer file with a
> precision of 0.1, and starting from -100. True values would be
> calculated as: true_value = (pixel_value * scale) + offset
>
> Note
>
> These values can be applied using -unscale during a gdal_translate
> run.
>
> **-offset** <value>
>
> Assign a specified offset value to output bands. If a single offset value is
> provided it will be set for all bands.
> Alternatively one offset value per band can be provided, in which case
> the number of offset values must match the number of bands. If no
> offset is needed, it recommended to set the value to 0. For more see
> scale.